# Android Alarm going off as soon as created

Tags: android, android-intent, timepicker, android-pendingintent

Edit: I have figured out that when you set the alarm for a time before the current time it imediately goes off

I am creating an alarm app that has an activity that you use to create the alarm, and then it registers it with the android system. The ***problem I am having is that as soon as you create the alarm it goes off.*** I have also seen some odd behaviour with further testing, if you change the time in the time picker ***before*** you change the name it goes off at the correct time if not it just goes off as soon as it is created. Here is my alarm class which is used to create the pending-intent for the alarm(at least the important parts):

```
public class Alarm {
private String name;
private int id;
private Calendar time;
private boolean on = true;

public Alarm(String name, int id, Calendar time) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setId(id);
    this.setTime(time);
}

public Alarm() {

}

    ...
public PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MathAlarmReceiverActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("name", getName());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
}


    ...
```

}

I thought that the problem might be where I created the intent, but when I changed the time in the time picker ***before*** I changed the name, it went off at the correct time so I was able to rule that out.

Next I have my Activity that actually has the time-picker:

```
public class EditActivity extends Activity {

    public static int CODE_EDIT = 100;
    public static int CODE_ADD = 101;
    Button doneButton;
    TimePicker tp;
    EditText editName;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
        doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                done();

            }
        });
        tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAlarmName);

        if (getIntent().getExtras().getInt("requestCode") == CODE_ADD) {
            setTitle("Add Alarm");
            doneButton.setText("Add Alarm");
        } else {
            doneButton.setText("Edit Alarm");
            editName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
            Calendar c = TimeUtils.stringToCalendar(getIntent().getExtras().getString("time"));
            tp.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            tp.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            setTitle("Edit Alarm");

        }
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

       ...

    private void done() {
        String name = editName.getText().toString().trim();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.getCurrentMinute());
        String time = TimeUtils.calendarToString(c);
        if (name.length() == 0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            b.setMessage("Please enter an alarm name!");
            b.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
            b.show();
        } else {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("name", name);
            returnIntent.putExtra("time", time);
            if (getIntent().getExtras().getInt("requestCode") == CODE_EDIT) {
                returnIntent.putExtra("id", getIntent().getExtras()
                        .getInt("id"));
                returnIntent.putExtra("on",
                        getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("on"));
            }

            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }



    ...

}
```

Then I thought well maybe when I didn't do it that specific way it somehow changed what was in the time-picker, but I wasn't sure how that could happen! Here I have my method for adding the alarm to the android system:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == EditActivity.CODE_EDIT) {
            dataSource.update_byID(
                    data.getExtras().getInt("id"),
                    TimeUtils.stringToCalendar(data.getExtras().getString(
                            "time")), data.getExtras().getString("name"),
                    data.getExtras().getBoolean("on"));
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            for(int i = 0; i < dataSource.getAllAlarms().size(); i++) {
                if(dataSource.getAllAlarms().get(i).getId() == data.getExtras().getInt("id")) {
                    Alarm tempAlarm = dataSource.getAllAlarms().get(i);
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tempAlarm.getTime()
                            .getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, tempAlarm
                            .createPendingIntent(this));
                    break;

                }
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == EditActivity.CODE_ADD) {
            Alarm tempAlarm = dataSource.createAlarm(
                    data.getExtras().getString("name"),
                    TimeUtils.stringToCalendar(data.getExtras().getString(
                            "time")));
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tempAlarm.getTime()
                    .getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, tempAlarm
                    .createPendingIntent(this));

        }
    }
    refreshList();

}
```

And also these are the methods I used to convert a Calendar to string and back, I thought maybe I made an error here, but I tested the methods and they work:

```
public static String calendarToString(Calendar c) {
    return String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR)) + ":"
            + getMinuteInReadableFormat(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
            + (((c.get(Calendar.AM_PM)) == Calendar.AM) ? "AM" : "PM");
}

public static Calendar stringToCalendar(String s) {
    String[] t = s.split(":");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.valueOf(t[0]));
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteToInt(t[1]));
    c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, (t[1].endsWith("AM") ? Calendar.AM : Calendar.PM));
    return c;
}

public static String convert12(String s) {
    String newString = null;
    if (s.startsWith("0")) {
        newString = s.replaceFirst("0", "12");
    }
    if (newString == null) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return newString;
    }
}

private static String getMinuteInReadableFormat(int m) {
    if (m < 10) {
        return "0" + String.valueOf(m);
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(m);
    }
}

private static int minuteToInt(String m) {
    String x = m;
    if (m.startsWith("0")) {
        x = m.replaceFirst("0", "");
    }
    String y = x.replace("AM", "");
    String z = y.replace("PM", "");
    return Integer.valueOf(z.trim());
}
```

My ***problem is that as soon as you create the alarm it goes off.*** I have also seen some odd behaviour with further testing, if you change the time in the time picker ***before*** you change the name it goes off at the correct time if not it just goes off as soon as it is created. And I am not sure what to do know because I don't know what the problem is.

Also Thank You for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: You are making a fairly simple task very complicated.  I'm finding it difficult to follow what you have going on here. I recommend that you reorganize - simplify.

Comment: @jason how would you suggest I simplify it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've solved the problem. For anyone that has a similar problem here is the solution. When I was creating an alarm for a time ***earlier than the current time*** it would go off immediately. The solution is to add the equivalent of 24 hours to the time you want when setting the alarm.